# SSIS web service task, can't execute web service

Tags: ssis

I have a web service that is called from my ssis.

Used to work fine in test mode, when moved to live environment I get the error :

[Web Service Task] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebserviceTaskException: Could not execute the Web method. The error is: Object reference not set to an instance of an object..    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebMethodInvokerProxy.InvokeMethod(DTSWebMethodInfo methodInfo, String serviceName, Object connection)    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTaskUtil.Invoke(DTSWebMethodInfo methodInfo, String serviceName, Object connection, VariableDispenser taskVariableDispenser)    at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.WebServiceTask.WebServiceTask.executeThread()".

We are using a proxy to access the web. Could this be a proxy problem. how to solve ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was simple proxy issue.

Don't forget to configure the proxy tab in your Http Connection Manager

Answer (score 2):

To help diagnose this, you might try using a script task and adding a Service Reference or Web Reference to the web service. Call the service within a try/catch block and log ex.ToString() if you get an exception. That way, you'll be sure to have all the details, and you can post them here in an edit to your question.

Answer (score 1):

It's also worth noting that SSIS cannot invoke services with spaces in the names. See the following for details:

http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/368606/ssis-web-service-task-cannot-call-services-with-a-space-in-the-name

This answer would have saved me time so I'm adding it in the hope it saves someone else some time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, except my cause was that I was attempting to pass an integer (Int32) as a web service parameter.  It looks like web service parameters in SSIS should always be strings.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using SSIS 2017 and none of the solutions worked for me. But, after changing the SQL Server used by the project, from 2017 to 2016 (or whatever version of SQL is installed), I was able to run the WebService task successfully.

Hope will help somebody.

[image]